# Console Application vs GUI?

Tags: performance, gui

I'm trying to develop a minimal MP3 player with some cool but light features. It is so simple that it doesn't matter if it is console application or not.

Since my purpose is to consume the sources as small as possible which one should I pick?

Extra info: I will be using a single textbox if it's going to be an application with GUI. Also, I am using VS 2010 C++

Comment: I think you are kidding yourself if you expect anyone other than techies and power users to run a command line application.

Comment: It's gonna be freeware so I don't mind. It actually has some features that the other players doesn't have.

Comment: It seems you already have concluded it will be a console app, so what is the purpose of posting this question?

Comment: Unless you plan on putting the software on an embedded device, your constraint of "it should use as few resources as possible" makes no sense from a UI perspective.

Comment: I am somehow always forced to justify my question... The thing is comsuming less memory and CPU and GPU. That's all I want to know.

Answer (score 3):

I would ask three questions:

First, **who is the target audience for the application?** Most non-technical users are unfamiliar with console or command line interfaces. Console apps are usually OK for technical users, since they are used to legacy console applications.

Second, **what platform will the application run on?** A console app may be a good way of keeping a consistent UI across platforms. Most platforms have very different GUI styles. I also assume this will run on Windows or a *nix where console apps are supported.

Third, **what are you trying to achieve?** For example, if you want to focus on an unobtrusive UI, many platforms have ways of achieving this, such as the Windows task tray or the Mac menu bar. A console app may not be the best solution.

If you want as few lines of source code as possible, a console app may not give you that. Many GUI development environments have GUI editors or helpers that make writing GUIs relatively straight forward. Console app libraries, by comparison, have not received the same attention.

Do you want to write a console app for the sake of writing a console app? You could write the application as a library, keeping the UI separate. Afterwards, you write a console app as one UI over the app for quick development then, when you have a better idea of the features and design, invest time in a more robust, feature rich GUI.

Ultimately, particularly if this is freeware, maybe experiment with a console UI or with both. Release it with the product and see who uses it. Maybe people might like it or parts of it.

Comment: The application will not require technical knowledge. It will run on Linux and Windows. I'm trying to achieve is consuming minimal CPU, RAM and GPU. It has the highest priority. Minimal file size for executable. It is going to be a single file. For example I can generate 20kb file if I use C#.NET but it has dependencies and 20MB+ memory comsumption even with an empty application.

Comment: Why is consuming so little CPU, RAM and GPU that important? 200 MB on a PC is nothing. If you want to write it in C/C++ and WTL or the console APIs you can probably get it down much further but it will likely take longer to write and be harder to debug. If this is an academic exercise, go ahead.